# How can I execute script every time when I input any command in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to execute bash script every time when I input any command in terminal, how can I catch exact moment when command is run?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Comment: I think this is the same question : https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Comment: As the question stands it is likely to be migrated to SuperUser and then closed as a duplicate. If you have some specific use case which makes the SuperUser answers inappropriate for your specific situation, now is the time to add that to this question. For example, if your question is about auditing an untrusted user the accepted answer to the SuperUser question is not appropriate, since it can easily be disabled.